# Как работает утилита sort -n в Linux со словами и числами?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сортировка, консоль

Не совсем понимаю, как работает sort в Linux, в случае, если в столбце есть как числа, так и слова/пробелы. Я думал, что если у утилиты не получается привести символы к числу, то она просто сравнивает два значения как строки. Но судя по выводу в консоль в моем терминале это работает не так, либо я что-то не понимаю.

Вот к примеру базовый пример:

```
apple 5
banana 23
banana 10

42 -42
-42 42
84 -84
orange 7
13
banana 8
banana 8
apple 3
orange 7
84
grape 15
apple
-13
banana 124
banana 14
14 banana
```

После сортировки  `sort -k 2 -n`

```
84 -84
42 -42

-13
13
14 banana
84
apple
apple 3
apple 5
orange 7
orange 7
banana 8
banana 8
banana 10
banana 14
grape 15
banana 23
-42 42
banana 124
```

Более простой пример

```
10 apple
2 orange
5 15 banana
strawberry
grape
```

После сортировки `sort -n`

```
grape fgh
strawberry hg
2 orange
5 15 banana
10 apple
```

Comment: В [спецификации POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html) описан алгоритм. Если я правильно понял, грубо говоря, если строку удаётся прочитать как число, то она сортируется по этому числу, а если нет, то берётся число 0, поэтому `grape` и `strawberry` получают число 0 и улетают в начало сортировки

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо, стало понятнее. Но будто бы все немного сложнее. Такое чувство, что кроме того, что ```grape``` и ```strawberry``` получают ноль, утилита их потом еще сортирует уже как строки.

Comment: Если есть несколько строк с одинаковыми значениями ключей, утилита [сортирует эти строки в алфавитном порядке](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html): `Finally, as a last resort when all keys compare equal, sort compares entire lines as if no ordering options other than --reverse (-r) were specified.`